# What's the correct php link for sharing blog posts on Facebook and Pinterest?

Tags: facebook, twitter, share, pinterest

I've created simple icons to share my blog posts on Facebook, Pinterest and Twitter. The Facebook link used to work, but now it doesn't. I'm not sure what to use for Pinterest. The Twitter link works just fine, although I'd like to include my Twitter handle.

Do you have any suggestions on how to get the Facebook link to work or what to use for Pinterest? Thank you.

Here's what I've been using:

```
<li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink();?>&t=<?php the_title(); ?>" target="_blank"><span class="icon-facebook-1"></span></a></li>

<li><a href="http://twitter.com/home/?status=<?php the_title(); ?> - <?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank""><span class="icon-twitter"></span></a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the `sharer.php` solution still works I think:

- https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.buzzfeed.com

Or what exactly isn't working for you? For Twitter, I think the Tweet Web Intent might be a solution for you.

- https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Great%20link&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.buzzfeed.com

See

- https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/web-intent
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/web

Comment: Thank you. I have everything working now. I followed a Crunchify tutorial. For Pinterest, this works: '$pinterestURL = 'https://pinterest.com/pin/create/bookmarklet/?media=[post-img]&url=[post-url]&description=[post-title]';
'